# Quotientes of afine group schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-schemes, group-schemes

Let $G=Spec(K[x_1,...,x_n])$ an afine group scheme and $H$ an subgroup scheme of $G$ then

-Can i say that $H$ is a afine group scheme, if not then when can I say it?

-How can I define the quotient (as a scheme) and  the resulting scheme is affine?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as your second question goes, in general, defining quotients of schemes is tricky. There is, however, way in which quotient functors can be defined. You first define it pointwise on each scheme and then "sheafify" (here the sheafification is on sheaves on the cateogory of schemes equipped with the fpqc topology). This involves some nontrivial algebraic geometry. Here is a reference that might help: http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/AGS.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might help if you give a precise definition of "subgroup scheme".  E.g. if you require that $H$ is a *closed* subgroup scheme, then $H$ will in particular be a closed subscheme of an affine scheme, and hence affine.

On the other hand, if $K = \mathbb C$ and $G = \mathbb G_a$ (otherwise known as $\mathbb G_a$, the additive group) then the morphisms $\mathbb Z \to G$
(where we think of $\mathbb Z$ as a discrete scheme; each point is just a copy of
Spec $\mathbb C$), given by sending each element $n \in \mathbb Z$ to the
corresponding closed point of $\mathbb G_a$, is a monomorphism, so that
certainly $\mathbb Z$ represents a group subfunctor of the functor of points
of $\mathbb G_a$ (so that it wouldn't be completely unreasonable to call
$\mathbb Z$ a subgroup scheme of $\mathbb G_a$), but $\mathbb Z$ is not an affine scheme (it has infinitely many
irreducible components).

In general, if $H$ is a closed subgroup scheme of the affine group scheme $G$,
then the quotient $G/H$ need not be affine.  E.g. if $G = GL_2$ and $H$
is the subgroup of upper triangular matrices, then $G/H = \mathbb P^1$, which is
not affine.

If $H$ is *reductive*, then $G/H$ *is* affine.

(Maybe I should assume that
$K$ has char. zero, for safety.  Then here is a sketch of the proof: Consider a s.e.s. of coherent sheaves on $G/H$.  Taking global sections is the same
as pulling back to a s.e.s. on $G$, taking global sections
of these pull-backs over $G$, and then passing to $H$-invariants.  Now
pulling back to $G$ is exact, since $G \to G/H$ is flat, and passing
to global sections over $G$ is exact, since $G$ is affine.  Finally, passing
to $H$-invariants is exact, because $H$ is reductive.  Thus passing to global sections is an exact functor on coherent sheaves on $G/H$, and so by Serre's
cohomological criterion, $G/H$ is affine.)

If $H$ is a *normal* closed subgroup scheme of $G$, so that $G/H$ is again a group scheme, then
I guess $G/H$ is also necessarily affine.

Comment: As a remark on your first point, I think that if H is a  subgroup scheme with finitely many components then the Chevalley Constructibility Theorem along with homogeneity of H actually implies that H is automatically closed in G.

Comment: @SiddharthVenkatesh: Thanks, that's a very helpful comment.